# Search for mobiles and click a particular mobile and print a particular review of the product in the console

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, e-commerce

When we search for mobiles on Amazon and click a particular mobile and print a particular review of the product in the console using selenium with java with cucumber framework, Its is not printing anything.

```
     @Then("Click on the add to cart button")
     public void click_on_the_add_to_cart_button() {

    Set<String> ids = driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it = ids.iterator();
    String parentId = it.next();
    String childId = it.next();
    driver.switchTo().window(childId);
    l1=new LoginPojo();
    btnClick(l1.getAddToCart());
    JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,10000)","");
    String data = driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //[@id=\"customer_review- R1R9S770F79ZNP\"]/div[4]/span/div/div[1]/span")).getText();
    System.out.println("Result: " + data);
}
```

Comment: After LoginPojo(), shouldnt you be switching back to the defaultcontent to grab the review?

Comment: But I thought like,I have to find the element for review using xpath and print it.

Comment: R1R9S770F79ZNP in your id, is that unique?

Comment: It is xpath for review when I found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works. I am trying to grab the 4 element from this [link](https://www.amazon.in/New-Apple-iPhone-Mini-64GB/dp/B08L5TTX14/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=smartphones&qid=1628562442&sr=8-2-spons&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEySDVBVUlXMU9XR1ZaJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNjk1MjI3MjNaTElCRkFUUlFJTyZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMzQ4MjIwMVQ4NVVEVFZURFA1VCZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU&th=1)

```
List<WebElement> reviews = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-hook='review']"));
        
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement reviewEle = reviews.get(4);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", reviewEle);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
System.out.println(reviewEle.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@id,'review-card')]/div[contains(@id,'customer_review')]//following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'small review-data')]//span[@data-hook='review-body']")).getText());
```